# Crawl links which have href within one quote

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

I use Scrapy to crawl some websites and I have problem with links where `href`'s have one quote  `href=' '` rather than double quotes `href=" "`.

And when I allow all links to be crawled with `allow()`, the result will only contain links formed with double quotes. How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `scrapy.contrib_exp.crawlspider.rules.Rule` and `SgmlLinkExtractor`?  I do n't think single quotes or double quotes matter. If you want all links to be extracted and associated with that particular rule, use

```
Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('.*', )), callback='parse_item')
```

as allow=() refers to empty tuple and hence no urls will be matched.

Comment: Yes i did this but always the same probleme.the link is:<a onmouseover="return function();" href = 'Details.asp?cod_ann=103473' >Example</a>.!!!!?

Comment: try inserting your html snippet in a txt file, use scrapy shell to open the text file and run SgmlLinkExtractor.extract_links(response). I have [<Link url='file:///C:/Users/foo/Desktop/Details.asp?cod_ann=103473' text=u'Example' >], so don't think its the problem

Comment: you don't see what? and what makes you think the link is not extracted